# In a hadoop cluster, should hive be installed on all nodes? Install Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Hadoop / Pig and I have just started reading the docs.
There are lots of blogs on installing Hadoop in cluster mode.
I know that Pig runs on top of Hadoop.

My question is: Hadoop is installed on all the cluster nodes.
Should I also install Pig on all the cluster nodes or only on the master node?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to install Hive Metastore and Hive Server on 2 different nodes. By default, hive uses derby database, but most of the people choose to go with MySQL so there will be a MYSQL server daemon also.
So not to confuse you anymore :

1. Install HiveServer and WebHcat Server on one node
2. Install Hive Metastore and MySQL server on another node.

This is the best practice. If you have any other doubt you can ask!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if the question is about Hive or Pig, but there's a difference between clients and servers.

For Hive, the master services are the Metastore and HiveServer2. You can install these daemons on the same server to improve network traffic between the metastore and the Hive query compiler. You only need one client to communicate with those masters.

For Pig, it communicates directly to YARN and HDFS (optionally Hive, if you use Hcatalog). Again, it's only a client, so only one hosts needs it.

It is generally preferred to have a dedicated set of machines for Hive and the backing RDBMS for the metastore (Mysql or Postgres being the more popular options)

You also don't need to "install Pig in the cluster". For example, I could grab the Hadoop XML configs and run some Pig code against the YARN cluster from any outside computer after downloading Pig locally (same applies to Spark)